# Why is context getting passed in to this method

Tags: android

I can't figure out why the context is getting passed in to this method: http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-Android/src/com/cloudtasks/Util.java#119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of the `URL_MAP` are the `Context`s. So you need the context to get the base url.

Comment: Yes I get that but why is it using the context as the key?

Comment: Because it indicates a specific instance of a service / app.